# Push...Against The Wall

Tags: meaning, usage

I have a question about phrases like this one:

> John **pushed** Jane **against** the wall.

The verb **push** refers to an active state of movement

> **push** down the street

the preposition **against** implies a stationary state

> the ladder **against** the wall

So the phrase

> **pushed** Jane **against**

is contradictory to me about motion.

Would this rewrite:

> John **pushed** Jane **toward** the wall, and **held** her **against** the wall.

which is less contradictory to me have the **same meaning**?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think "against" implies a stationary state.  "against" can mean "in the direction of and into contact with".

Comment: Walls tend to turn movers into stationary objects, so you are pretty close.

Comment: "The boat was moving **against** the tide, and moving rather fast, thanks to the newly-installed steam turbine". Natural language is not legalese. Brevity has a great deal of precedence over meticulousness, and is the soul of wit. (0:

Comment: The rewrite would be more wordy, but not better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is founded upon a misapprehension of the meaning of *against*.

Comment: @StoneyB: That would seem to be the usual reason for asking a question. (I was pleasantly surprised to discover that only two of the Related questions in the sidebar about "against" were by this same poster, and neither is directly related.)

Comment: @StoneyB I think the OP is kind of correct (and kind of wrong of course too). It seems to me that the PP taken by *PUSH* seems to be able to be either purely directional, or to describe the goal or endpoint of the thing being pushed. So in *I pushed against the tide*, it describes a direction, but in *I pushed them against the wall*, the PP *against the wall* does in fact describe the resultative situation with respect to *them*, and not really a direction, maybe.

Comment: @Araucaria Fersher. Most P have this sort of ambivalence, and most can occur in situations like this where both direction and position are implied: *He set it **on** the table*, *He whacked him on the head* (though where I come from we'd say *He whacked him upside the head*--an eloquent P of which *CGEL* regrettably takes no notice).

Answer (score 3):

If the push caused Jane to make contact with the wall, then the initial sentence is correct and would likely be something seen in domestic violence cases where someone is moved to being put adjacent to a boundary.

The rewrite weakens the statement by adding words that don't quite have the same punch, metaphorically speaking. You could say, "John pushed Jane to the wall and pinned her against the wall," though this is pretty close to the original sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Collision is part of the definition:

> **[Against](https://www.google.com/search?q=against)**: in or into physical contact with (something), typically so as to be supported by or **collide with it**.
>   <sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

Thus Jane's collision was caused by John – she was pushed against the wall.

The rewrite is weaker. If Jane was pushed towards the wall, the implication is that she did not hit the wall. If I push Jane against the wall, there is the collision. By changing the wording, you remove that collision, and thus the violent impact. So the sentence feels softer.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, **against** means **to be in contact with**.
**Adjacent** would only mean **next to** which may or may not include **contact**.
**Upon** would imply **on top of**.

John obviously **pushed** Jane **until** she **came in contact** with **the side of a wall**. Whether or not it was **against her will** and he **held** her there once she came in **contact with the wall** could be a topics for discussion, but is usually implicitly assumed.

Not sure why you might think the statement **has too much information**, if anything, the reader would be intrigued as to **what happened next**.

Comment: @meatie not sure how you got a **combined meaning**. **Against** is to be **in contact with**, **touching**. To be **pushed against** is to be **pushed** until coming **into contact with**, the **towards** is caused by the **pushing** in the example given. Usually, two things must be **brought together** to come **into contact**, so I suppose one might think there is an implicit **towards**.  It's standard usage by native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Try *John **shoved** Jane against the wall*. That seems to have even more movement, at least violent movement. There is no problem with *shove* here. And since *shove* and *push* can be synonyms  there's not much of a problem with *push*. A suggested rewrite would include *up*, as in *John pushed Jane up against the wall*. This also suggests motion and contact with the wall.

As others have said *against* does not have to refer to something stationary. *He threw the coins against the wall*. Yes the wall stops both the coins and Jane, but it's clear that you can push or shove or throw something or someone against a wall, and motion is involved.